# How to call FatSecret Api from Android Env?

Tags: javascript, android, rest

currently I would like to use the Fatsecret API to make an Android app. They have REST and JS APIs primarily for Web development, I guess, web development is not my forte. Can someone enlighten me as how to use this API from Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have a REST API then you could use it in your Android app.
Using a REST API is nothing but making http requests to an url, and getting a response (usually in JSON, or XML format), and eventually parsing that response.

To make http requests to a server you could use the [HttpClient](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient). And to parse the response you could use, for XML: [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), and for JSON: [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for example.

If these things appear new to you, then pause a bit, spend some time until you grasp the concept, then come back to Fatsecret API.

Answer (score 0):

They also have a [java library](http://platform.fatsecret.com/api/Default.aspx?screen=lib) and a [java client](http://ranesr.github.io/fatsecret4j/) that could take care of the management of the http requests for you. Though it is not clear if the library can be mapped straight to the Android API.